# number/numbers to list by using input()

Tags: python, list, input, numbers

Maybe this is a very basic question but i am a beginner in python and couldnt find any solution. i was writing a python script and got stuck because i cant use python lists effective. i want user to input (number or numbers) and store them in a python list as integers. for example user can input single number 1 or multiple numbers seperated by comma 1,2,3 and i want to save them to a list in integers.
i tried this ;

```
def inputnumber():
    number =[]
    num = input();
    number.append(num)
    number = map(int,number)
return (number)
def main():
    x = inputnumber()
print x
```

for a single number there is no problem but if the the input is like 1,2,3 it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
main()
File "test.py", line 21, in main
x = inputnumber()
File "test.py", line 16, in inputnumber
number = map(int,number)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Also i have to take into account that user may input characters instead of numbers too. i have to filter this. if the user input a word a single char. i know that i must use try: except. but couldn't handle. i searched the stackoverflow and the internet but in the examples that i found the input wanted from user was like;

```
>>>[1,2,3]
```

i found something this [Mark Byers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542767/1948951) in stackoverflow but couldn't  make it work 
i use python 2.5 in windows.

Sorry for my English. Thank you so much for your helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your function, you can directly convert `num` into a list by calling `split(',')`, which will split on a comma - in the case a comma doesn't exist, you just get a single-element list. For example:

```
In [1]: num = '1'

In [2]: num.split(',')
Out[2]: ['1']

In [3]: num = '1,2,3,4'

In [4]: num.split(',')
Out[4]: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

You can then use your function as you have it:

```
def inputnumber():
    num = raw_input('Enter number(s): ').split(',')
    number = map(int,num)
    return number

x = inputnumber()
print x
```

However you can take it a step further if you want - `map` here can be replaced by a list comprehension, and you can also get rid of the intermediate variable `number` and return the result of the comprehension (same would work for `map` as well, if you want to keep that):

```
def inputnumber():
    num = raw_input('Enter number(s): ').split(',')
    return [int(n) for n in num]

x = inputnumber()
print x
```

If you want to handle other types of input without error, you can use a `try/except` block (and handle the `ValueError` exception), or use one of the fun methods on strings to check if the number is a digit:

```
def inputnumber():
    num = raw_input('Enter number(s): ').split(',')
    return [int(n) for n in num if n.isdigit()]

x = inputnumber()
print x
```

This shows some of the power of a list comprehension - here we say 'cast this value as an integer, but only if it is a digit (that is the `if n.isdigit()` part).

And as you may have guessed, you can collapse it even more by getting rid of the function entirely and just making it a one-liner (this is an awesome/tricky feature of Python - condensing to one-liners is surprisingly easy, but can lead to less readable code in some case, so I vote for your approach above :) ):

```
print [int(n) for n in raw_input('Number(s): ').split(',') if n.isdigit()]
```

Comment: @Geomatics No problem at all, happy it helps :) And sorry, just noticed your edit about handling other words - I'll drop that in as well.

Answer (score -1):

`input` is not the way to go here - it evaluates the input as python code. Use `raw_input` instead, which returns a string. So what you want is this:

```
def inputnumber():
    num = raw_input()
    for i, j in enumerate(num):
        if j not in ', ':
            try:
                int(num[i])
            except ValueError:
                #error handling goes here
    return num

def main():
    x = inputnumber()
    print x
```

I guess all it is is a long-winded version of RocketDonkey's answer.

Comment: But if the input is single number this gives an error: `code` TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I edited my answer - it should work now

Comment: -1: You (correctly) advise against using `input` because it evaluates the input, and then use `eval` to evaluate the input anyway. This is therefore just as unsafe as using `input` directly.

Comment: @Blair that's true, I'll change it (although Rocket's answer would probably better anyway)

Comment: Your original solution was a clever way of handling it - you can actually get around the pitfalls of `eval` by using the `literal_eval` function in the `ast` module (although on second thought, that won't work in the case of somebody entering a word as opposed to a number, so just ignore me :) ).