# Removing an integer from a list (both input from user)

Tags: python

I want to write a function that will remove a certain integer from a list. Both of the values are input. For example, `removeValues([1, 2, 3], 3)` would return the list `[1, 2]`:

```
def removeValues(aList, n):
    newList = []
    if n in aList:
        aList.remove(n)

        newList.append(aList)
    else:
        return False
```

I am not sure if `.remove` is the right way to go.

Comment: But there is already a method `list.remove` for that ...

Comment: Why are you appending your list to another list ? `[[1,2]]` Just remove it and presto ! `[1,2]`

Comment: *"I am not sure if .remove is the right way to go"* - have you tested it? Did it work?

Comment: I tested the list.remove but it has an error.  builtins.TypeError: descriptor 'remove' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int' So its saying it got an int and wanted a list. But the thing I want removed is an int....?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all occurences of a value from a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: Are you trying to remove a single occurrence of that value, or every occurrence? Does `removeValues([1, 2, 3, 3], 3)` return `[1, 2]` or `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @jlnabais I looked there and all examples are not with user input. There is just a given list in the function that is then messed with. Does it not matter if the list is user input or not?

Comment: @zayora it should remove all the values in the list. So it should return [1,2]

Comment: @wahlysadventures you can get the list from input and then delete all the occurrences of a given value. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177582/number-numbers-to-list-by-using-input) for how to input a list. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def removeValues(aList, n):
    return [ i for i in aList if i != n ]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
list(filter(lambda x : x != 3, [1,2,3]))
```

Use filter, Filter takes a function reference and list of elements. the function is written to accept a list element and return true or false based on the desired predicate like `x != 3`. for every element the function checks the predicate and only if the condition return True the element is included in the output list.

As said in the comments, a simple remove on the list will do the job.

Comment: Where would this line of code fit into the function? The first line after the function is defined?

Comment: this is a complete substitute for your function

Answer (score 0):

A function that will remove all occurrences of a specific value from a list could be written like so:

```
>>> def removeAll(list, value):
...     while value in list:
...         list.remove(value)
...
>>> a = [1,2,3,3,4]
>>> removeAll(a, 3)
>>> print( a )
[1,2,4]
```